# Adding a button to any website using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript but I am not new to programming. What I want to do is just add a button to any webpage that when clicked it'll call the alert function saying "hello world". Thanks.

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Did you do any research to solve your problem? What was the result. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Look into the following tutorials.These will help you to gain competency in javascript(with your effort):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/

http://webteacher.com/javascript/

Comment: Yeah I just got done with the w3schools tutorial. It has no info on adding buttons to pages lol..

Comment: @Marc: [Many people (myself included) will advise you to **avoid** w3schools.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Lol, why? Just curious. Edit: clicked the link, I see. I noticed their bad code formatting but just ignored it..

Answer (score 0):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MJx8b/

```
<input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="My Button" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click",function(){
       alert("Hello World");
    },false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, where do i actually put this code and "execute" it. Do i just put it in a notepad and save it with a specific extension?

Comment: well, you should learn HTML markup and understand a typical markup schema, but for demonstration purposes: yes. Save it as `.html`. Additionally when you save, on windows, save as type: "All files" and not *.txt

Comment: Yeah i'll get around to html, it's just so boring lol. But is this a way to add a button to any current website i'm currently on?

Comment: no unless you own the site and is able to update the HTML on the targeted server. however if you're looking to add a button to any site for you only... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Yeah, wanted to do it client sided only, so I'll take a look at that thanks.